# Avoiding memory leaks when deleting data of a template Object. (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, memory, destructor

Assume the following struct:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct A{
  T* pointer;
  void clearData(){
    //delete data pointer is pointing to
    data->~T(); //call destructor?
    pointer = nullptr;
  }
};
```

If I want to provide a function that clears the Data where `pointer` is pointing to - how would I go about this? I am aware of the `new/delete`, `new[]/delete[]` and `malloc()/free()` combinations but since `T` is templated I dont't know if the data was allocated using `new`, `new[]` or `malloc()`. From my understanding the destructor should always free up the allocated memory. So if I explicitly call the destructor there should be no memory leaks (if the destructor of the object is implemented correctly).
Are my assumptions correct or are there cases where this could lead to problems? If so please provide an example so I get a better understanding of the issue.

**Note**:
Answers like "you should use smart pointers because explicitly calling the destructor is bad practice" are not helpful as I am trying to understand **WHY** it would cause issues in my case. And I see explicit destructor calls as a valid option if it can't lead to any issues.

Comment: `T` is just a type, nothing more. It has no effect on how you manage the `pointer`. What is important is how the `T` object that `pointer` is pointing at was created, and this code simply does not convey that information. You can't call the `~T()` destructor directly if the object wasn't created with `placement-new` to begin with.  You can't `delete` the object if it wasn't created with `new`. You can't call `free()` if the memory wasn't allocated with `malloc()`. And so on. You need that information to make an informed decision.

Comment: Everything created with `new` should be free'd with `delete`. And `delete` will invoke the destructor if there is any.

Comment: With that said, do you ***really*** need  pointer? What for? What is the use-case for a pointer instead of an actual object? And if you need a pointer, think of the ownership management of the object, and use either `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` as applicable.

Comment: Generally you shouldn't deallocate memory you didn't allocate. If `pointer` isn't pointing to an object you created (eg in your constructor), leave it alone.

Comment: Exactly this is the Issue. I don't know how the object was created but I want to delete it in any case without any memory leaks.

Comment: @conixtract - If you don't know how it was created, then you can't release the memory.

Comment: @conixtract if you did not create the object yourself, then you are not responsible for freeing it UNLESS ownership of it was transferred to you. And in that case, whoever does that transfer should tell you exactly how to free it properly, either explicitly in code via the use of smart pointers, or else in documentation. If you don't have either, then you can't free it reliably.

Answer (score 4):

> From my understanding the destructor should always free up the allocated memory.

No. Destructor should release *owned resources*. It is not clear that `A` owns anything, especially if it didn't allocate the resource on its own, but got it from somewhere else. And resources are not just allocated memory (could be e.g. open file handle), but that's not really related to the topic.

> So if I explicitly call the destructor there should be no memory leaks (if the destructor of the object is implemented correctly).

Absolutely not. You are not allowed to call destructor of an object unless it was created with placement `new`. And if it was, calling destructor will do what `~T()` does, but will do nothing to the memory it was occupying, which likely still needs to be released.

> explicitly calling the destructor is bad practice

It's not bad practice, it's straight up Undefined Behaviour (except for that one case mentioned earlier).

---

In your case, `A` should not take ownership of `data` and make it clear in documentation that it wants a handle to `T` which will not be released in any way.

If you really think `A` should own `data`, you need to also accept a deleter that will be able to release `data` properly, because only the caller has knowledge on how to release it correctly (if it needs releasing at all) - just like `std::unique_ptr` does. And at this point, you could also just accept `std::unique_ptr` and forget about the issue altogether.

Comment: Thanks this was exactly the level of detail and explanation I needed.

Comment: @conixtract If my answer helped, you can click the tick under voting buttons to accept it